# Apply cookies to Selenium Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I have a cookies

```
[{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":-62135596800.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":false,"name":"m_pixel_ratio","path":"/","sameSite":"Unspecified","secure":true,"session":true,"storeId":null,"value":"1","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1634203061.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":false,"name":"locale","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"en_US","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1696670252.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":true,"name":"datr","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"LLteYam22wkYyFYIKCrpCs9c","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1696670360.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":true,"name":"sb","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"LLteYWAtTMTWsrsOIkyok3WD","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1641374352.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":true,"name":"fr","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"0FaY2AlCSxvGqz26J.AWWafU9uVQgCnqMy4ONnY73m70g.BhXrss.67.AAA.0.0.BhXruV.AWWa3brVb2I","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1665134356.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":false,"name":"c_user","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"100053629699795","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1665134356.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":true,"name":"xs","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"42%3AMA1VE7kIYdwHbw%3A2%3A1633598358%3A-1%3A-1","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1634289692.0,"hostOnly":true,"httpOnly":false,"name":"wd","path":"/","sameSite":"Lax","secure":true,"session":false,"storeId":null,"value":"975x482","id":1}]
```

And I want to apply it to my selenium chrome driver
First, I convertsed false --> False, true --> True, null --> None

**My code**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
cookies = l = [{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":-62135596800.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":False,"name":"m_pixel_ratio","path":"/","sameSite":"Unspecified","secure":True,"session":True,"storeId":None,"value":"1","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1634201515.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":False,"name":"locale","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"en_US","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1696668706.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":True,"name":"datr","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"IrVeYbWM6wEFI2zwhF6uAUPk","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1696668813.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":True,"name":"sb","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"IrVeYXpwEz32v1aJtzpM53LE","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1641372807.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":True,"name":"fr","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"0tWy03JUhmdiJMAjG.AWUBQFbT2SoDeM4YYE2QHAcrLg0.BhXrUi.fw.AAA.0.0.BhXrWL.AWU-Amt7swQ","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1665132810.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":False,"name":"c_user","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"100073263948757","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1665132810.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":True,"name":"xs","path":"/","sameSite":"None","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"26%3AsmHFqe8B8ZrFdQ%3A2%3A1633596812%3A-1%3A-1","id":1},{"domain":".facebook.com","expirationDate":1634289593.0,"hostOnly":True,"httpOnly":False,"name":"wd","path":"/","sameSite":"Lax","secure":True,"session":False,"storeId":None,"value":"975x482","id":1}]
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("facebook.com")
```

I have an error, How can I fix it?

```
 240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
```

Comment: in order to set cookies you need to be at that domain... (so your driver.get("facebook.com") should be first.  (also be careful when posting cookies here... they could include "remember me" or session type credentials...)

Comment: Also a json<->dict conversion should be performed via `json.loads` and `json.dumps`